# How to get remaining timeout in Django cache

Tags: django, memcached, django-cache

I'm throttling the post requests on a view that lets users add articles.
I'm currently using a decorator like so:

```
def throttle_post(func, duration=60):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            remote_addr = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') or \
                          request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            key = '%s.%s' % (remote_addr, request.get_full_path())
            if cache.get(key):
                messages.add_message(
                request, messages.ERROR, 'you cant add articles so fast, try waiting another {} seconds.format(remaining))
                return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            else:
                cache.set(key, 1, duration)
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
return inner
```

I want to display in the message how many seconds are remaining for the timeout.

thanks

Comment: What client are you using for memcached?

Comment: I'm new to using caches, is memcachier the client? I'm running off Heroku

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter. This isn't possible, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515770/memcache-expiration-times

Comment: So I can' tell my users how long they have left to wait?

Comment: Not with this approach. You could store the expiration datetime rather than 1  and calculate it that way. It won't be perfect, but it should be useable.

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible to do, if you want it you have to cache the value to another memory like redis or etc